# jsTree ajax - Get the return value from called web service function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, jstree

I have implemented a jsTree created with a code like this:

```
}).jstree({
        "json_data": {
            "ajax": {
                "url": '<% =  ResolveClientUrl("../GetTree.asmx/FullTree") %>',
                "async": true,
                "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "dataType": "json",
                "success": function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    alert("Transmission Success.");
                    alert(data);
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                    alert("Parsing JSON Success.");
                    // Can I access the return value of the web service FullTree function here?
                    return data.d;
                },
                "data": function (n) {
                    return {
                        id: nodoIniziale,
                        level: 0
                    };
                },
            },
            "progressive_render": true
        },
```

The ASP.NET function is like:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public int MacchineFullTree()
{
        List<jsTreeNewNode> nodes = new List<jsTreeNewNode>();
        int retValue;
        // ============== 
        // Code that creates the Tree and assign retValue = xxx
        // ============== 
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string nodesSerialized = serializer.Serialize(nodes);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length",        nodesSerialized.Length.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Connection", "Close");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(nodesSerialized);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();

        return retValue;
```

How can I access the web service return value? (If this makes sense)
(Even better would be to return an object from the web service function, instead of an int value... ;-))

**IMPORTANT EDIT**

If my web service function would simply be: `public int MacchineFullTree() { return 9999; }`
then in the **success** function I could get the return value interrogating **data.d**.

However in my case I am "forcing" the server response with `HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(nodesSerialized);` and interrogating `data.d` i get `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this feasible and *simple* solution ;-)
Instead of using the return value of the function, I have "enhanced" a bit more the tree nodes,
and in the root node I add the value as an attribute of the node istelf:

```
rootNode.retValue = xxx
```

(of course to do this I have modified the jsTreeNode class).

Drawback: now **all** the nodes of the tree have this attribute, so the lenght of the server response has grown bigger